# Vue: Add a class to a component with a specific id

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Sup,

To avoid creating for each of my projects one template I created an array containing the data I pass into the template.

```
projects: [
            {id: 1, name: 'Project1', titel:...},
            {id: 2, name: 'Project2', titel:...},
           
        ],`
```

I created a v-for loop to create a list of projects.

```
<div v-for="(project, index) in projects" :key="index" class="project" :class="project.classes">
     <button type="button" @click="showModalFor(project)">Click</button>
</div>

// create one modal for each project
<div v-for="(project, index) in projects" :key="index">
        <ProjectModal :id="project.id" :name="project.name" ... />
</div>
```

Here comes the tricky part for me: I don´t know how to add my "enter" class to the clicked project:

```
showModalFor(project) {
        
}
```

My approach was to add a boolean inside of my array and toggle the clicked project with it:

```
<ProjectModal v-if="showProject = true" :id="project.id" :name="project.name" ... />
```

The only problem is that I really need to add a class to a specific project so that my animation works. With this approach the projects popping up too fast.

Comment: Try to use `v-show` instead of `v-if`, `v-if` will re-render everything, meanwhile `v-show` is equal to `display: none;` or `display:true;`

Comment: Good catch, I ll try it. Still the same. I need to add a class to the modal in order to make the transition work.

Comment: Then you can put `showProject` in `<ProjectModal` class. For the example `<ProjectModal :class="showProject ? 'class-show' : 'class-hide'" ....` the class will be appended to first parent in `ProjectModal` component

Comment: Why do you need to add "enter" class ? Are you using Vue [transitions](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Overview) ? Also what is the point of rendering multiple modals if only one modal can be displayed at the time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't understand why you need to add any classes anywhere to show a modal. Just use a `v-if` and Vue [transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Overview)

Also, if "modal" means what it usually means, only one can be shown at the time. Rendering multiple modals makes no sense. Just use only one and use prop to set what project it should show...

See the example below:

```js
Vue.component('modal', {
  props: ['project'],
  template: `
  <transition name="fade">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close" @click="$emit('close')">&times;</span>
        <div> Id: {{ project.id }} </div>
        <div> Name: {{ project.name }} </div>
      </div>    
    </div>
  </transition>
  `
})

const vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: function() {
    return {
      activeProject: null,
      projects: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'Project1',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Project2',
        },
      ],
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.modal {  
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fade-enter-active {   
   transition: transform 0.375s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1), opacity 0.375s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.375s ease-in-out;
}

.fade-leave-active {   
   transition: transform 0.375s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1), opacity 0.375s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.375s ease-in-out;
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(project, index) in projects" :key="project.id">
    <button type="button" @click="activeProject = project">{{ project.name }}</button>
  </div>
  
  <modal v-if="activeProject" :project="activeProject" @close="activeProject = null"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, I see your point. It s way bettet your way. One thing which still not working for me: i want to add a transition when the "modal" comes in which scales from 0.6 to 1. I added:

transform: scale(0.6);
  transition: transform 0.375s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1),
    opacity 0.375s ease-in-out, border-radius 0.375s ease-in-out;

to the fade-leave class which works when the container leaves but not the other wqay around.

Comment: Sorry but it is really hard to understand what effect exactly you are trying achieve. I changed the sample to something ....maybe close. But I am far away from being expert on CSS and transitions. Read the docs, understand when and what classes Vue applies and it should not be hard. Or ask another question because this is far from the scope of this one. HTH

Comment: Yeah I sorry for the inconvience, I am a newbie in Vue and trying to  understand eveyrthing. You helped me a lot! Thanks again